# ASP.NET Int32 Eval error

Tags: asp.net, eval

I have this line:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="awsImage" runat="server" Target="_blank" 
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>' Width='<%# Eval("ImageWidth").ToString() %>'
Height='<%# Eval("ImageHeight").ToString() %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
```

And I get this error:

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit'

I also have tried simple Eval without .ToString but I get this error: This is the exact error I get if I use the Eval without .ToString

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: what is the result of your Eval Expression? You have to leave away ToString anyway

Comment: This is the exact error I get if I use the Eval without .ToString

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Yes, but what is the return value of your Eval?? If you have an InvalidCast Exception the result must be of the wrong type.

Comment: the value is an Int32 which I pass to Eval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="awsImage" runat="server" Target="_blank" 
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>' 
Width='<%# Unit.Pixel(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ImageWidth"))) %>'
Height='<%# Unit.Pixel(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ImageHeight"))) %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: then I get this error:

Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit' from its string representation '<%= Eval("ImageWidth").ToString() %>' for the 'Width' property.

Comment: Quick question Are you using GRID or any binding control?

Comment: with your new answer,I get this error: CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit'

Comment: I have changed all, also pasted your complete answer, and I get this:

CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22157/discussion-between-dan-hunex-and-mario-m)

Comment: I would not use Convert.ToInt32, as the Expression of Eval("...") is already of type int and you can use a simple type cast, but of course it works as well.

Answer (score 1):

I checked on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.aspx). `Height` and `Width` are of type `Unit`:

```
Width='<%# new Unit((int)Eval("ImageWidth")) %>' 
Height='<%# new Unit((int)Eval("ImageHeight")) %>'
```

or by using the static method `Unit.Pixel`

```
Width='<%# Unit.Pixel((int)Eval("ImageWidth")) %>' 
Height='<%# Unit.Pixel((int)Eval("ImageHeight")) %>'
```

Because the expression is evaluated on the server, you have to provide the correct data type (the compiler generates the code).

Comment: Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a closing )

Comment: CS0118: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: puuh, that was a hard one. No I got it. Sorry it took me so long

Comment: Thanks ! it works with (Unit)(int)Eval or the above answer which I have selected as the correct answer. With Unit((int)Eval... does not work